# How to convert Figma project to React using Anima?

Tags: reactjs, figma

I've been stuck to convert the Figma project given by one of my client, to React using Anima. I've tried but, finding it hard to implement. Any resources or suggestions is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also struggled with anima, but in the end I managed to get some React code exported. They have some documentation in the Advanced section of the Guides.

See if you have better success with Desech Studio which also imports figma and exports react.
Here's their [github repo](https://github.com/desech/studio-react) for react.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the pxCode plugin, which also converts Figma into React component.
pxCode support some React features such as

- pure component
- sub-render
- naming props